# coc.nvim Server clangd failed to start: Error: spawn UNKNOWN issue -4094

Tags: neovim, clangd, coc.nvim

so my issue is I installed neovim and nodejs and coc.nvim in windows
I want to set it up for c++ and I did everything it asked
but when I open cpp files I got an error message like : Server clangd failed to start: Error: spawn UNKNOWN
here is the :CocInfo

```
## versions

vim version: NVIM v0.9.1
node version: v18.16.1
coc.nvim version: 0.0.82-'2280f9a 2023-06-26 10:37:36 +0800'
coc.nvim directory: C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\nvim-data\plugged\coc.nvim
term: undefined
platform: win32

## Log of coc.nvim

2023-07-07T13:09:16.419 INFO (pid:28784) [plugin] - coc.nvim initialized with node: v18.16.1 after 164
2023-07-07T13:09:22.565 INFO (pid:28784) [services] - LanguageClient clangd state change: stopped => starting
2023-07-07T13:09:22.568 INFO (pid:28784) [services] - LanguageClient clangd state change: starting => stopped
2023-07-07T13:09:22.569 ERROR (pid:28784) [services] - Server clangd failed to start: Error: spawn UNKNOWN
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:757:9)
    at C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\nvim-data\plugged\coc.nvim\build\index.js:69379:47
    at async LanguageClient.createConnection (C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\nvim-data\plugged\coc.nvim\build\index.js:68714:28)
    at async LanguageClient._start (C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\nvim-data\plugged\coc.nvim\build\index.js:68340:30)
    at async Object.start (C:\Users\EXO\AppData\Local\nvim-data\plugged\coc.nvim\build\index.js:69889:17) {
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}
2023-07-07T13:09:34.026 INFO (pid:28784) [attach] - receive notification: showInfo []
```

[CocConfig data about clangd.path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN04Y.png)

[CocInfo issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od535.png)

is anyone had the same issue?
there was nothing to find and solve the issue

I tried ccls but it showed the same error message and clangd.path shows the same error

Comment: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/issues/4684

Answer (score 0):

The `clangd` binary downloaded by coc-clangd is broken, caused by unzipper with node v18.16.1, solutions:

1. upgrade your node to v20, delete the broken clangd binary, run `:CocCommand clangd.install`
2. or download clangd from GitHub release, and set `clangd.path` to it.